TP Link UE200 fails to initialize during boot
I had ordered a USB to Lan adapter from TP link (link) which used to work perfectly fine around 6-8 months ago in Ubuntu Server 20.04 running Raspberry PI 4B (4GB RAM) and I recently tried to connect it to same hardware and OS and it fails to show the interface. It doesn't show up in lsusb but if unplug and plug it it works fine what could be the problem?
dmesg
[    2.535403] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.615603] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    2.807586] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    2.999391] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    3.079588] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    3.271585] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    3.991400] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    3.991629] usb 1-1.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[    4.227594] usb 1-1.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[    4.435387] usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[    4.519396] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[    4.519629] usb 1-1.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[    4.727670] usb 1-1.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[    4.935901] usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 8, error -71

lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0eef:0005 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0461:0010 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP PR1101U / Primax PMX-KPR1101U Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

